# Unknown type name QML_ELEMENT

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In the new Qt 5.15.0 there is a new declarative way to register C++ types for usage in QML. I followed the steps given in **Qt Help** (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-an-instantiable-object-type) but it givens to me the following error:

```
/.../randomnumbergenerator.h:10: error: ‘QML_ELEMENT’ does not name a type
     QML_ELEMENT
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The class's definition is, for the moment:

```cpp
#ifndef RANDOMNUMBERGENERATOR_H
#define RANDOMNUMBERGENERATOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRandomGenerator>

class RandomNumberGenerator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_SINGLETON

public:
    explicit RandomNumberGenerator(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

};

#endif // RANDOMNUMBERGENERATOR_H
```

**EDIT:** I already added to the `.pro` file the following:

```
CONFIG += c++11 qmltypes
QML_IMPORT_NAME = SimpleRng
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As they point out in [the Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/115231/qml_element-does-not-name-a-type-in-qt-5-15/3) you have to include `<qml.h>` (or `<QtQml>`)

Comment: Thanks! But it is better (prettier) that you include `<QtQml>` instead of `<qml.h>`

Comment: Doing only this usually not solves all problems. You will still get a compilation error in the auto-generated `<classname>_qmltyperegistrations.cpp`:

`error: randomnumbergenerator.h: No such file or directory`

In the same page you can find the solution: adding the class's directory to the `INCLUDEPATH` qmake variable:

`INCLUDEPATH += src/core/RandomNumberGenerator`

You may want to point out this.

Comment: There is also a warning that I have not being able to solve: `warning: Failure to find: simplerng_metatypes.json`

Comment: I know that new features usually are buggy, but it is sad that *The Qt Company* do not even document this. Even knowing that this is a LTS release. And still they said in its post that Qt 5.15.0 is the *most stable of all Qt 5 releases*. Pffff :/

Answer (score 2):

The [preconditions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#preconditions) section of the documentation you quoted states that

> All the macros mentioned below are available from the qqml.h header. You need to add the following code to the files using them in order to make the macros available:
>
> `#include <QtQml/qqml.h>`

That seems to be the canonical answer and may avoid the issues that @lateus mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The documentation available when I first published this issue was lacking several things that were added in subsequent patches of Qt 5. Actually all the issues in my comments are already well documented in the official doc. The lack of doc is sadly a common problem in almost all .0 releases of Qt.

Comment: In Qt6 the [preconditions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#preconditions) suggest to

`#include <QtQml/qqmlregistration.h>`

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

```
#ifndef CONNECTIONHANDLER_H
#define CONNECTIONHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>//include QtQml like so 

class ConnectionHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool alive READ alive  NOTIFY deviceChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name NOTIFY deviceChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString address READ address NOTIFY deviceChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool requireAddressType READ requireAddressType CONSTANT)

    QML_ELEMENT//and use here or where needed
public:
    explicit ConnectionHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:

};

#endif // CONNECTIONHANDLER_H
```